# zoom in PDF reader in vue component

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I would like to make a **page** with **vue.js** and **laravel**, where I can **show a pdf in a vue-component**. I found a great lib for that [vue-pdf](https://github.com/FranckFreiburger/vue-pdf), what can show the PDFs.

My **problem** is that the **PDF reader can not zoom (in/out)**, is there any solution for that, (e.g.: css / js hack) or can anybody recommend me an another pdf reader in vue system?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to take a look at [npm's panzoom](https://www.npmjs.com/package/panzoom)

```
<template>
    <pdf @loaded="onLoad" src="yourpdf.pdf" page="1" ref="mypdf"></pdf>
</template>

<script>
import pdf from 'vue-pdf';
import panzoom from 'panzoom';
export default {
    components: {
      pdf
    }, 
    methods: {
        onLoad() {
            panzooom(this.$refs.mypdf);
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Its working if I wrap the <pdf> element into a div, and I give that div the ref value. :)
sry for the late response.